# Client-side DataSource in place of DriverManager

Tags: java, web-applications, database-connection, datasource, connection-pooling

In Java, I use DriverManager for client side code and Connection pooled DataSource for server side code. Is this the standard way to do it or is it possible to use a separate DataSource on the client side as well?

Comment: How can you use `DriverManager` in the client side? Don't you access the DB via the server?

Comment: Sorry about calling it "client-side". I meant code that doesn't reside on a server, primarily standard desktop applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know if you can use a connection pool outside of a server application.

You can, either you to write your own pool implementation, which is going to be tedious... or you can use a library like commons dbcp or c3po.

Hope this helps

Comment: Alright, so DriverMangager is still the best choice for desktop applications then?

Comment: A connection pool is not an alternative to DriverManager. DriverManager is the part of jdk that loads a driver and makes it available to you. The question is whether you want to have a pool of connections, rather than opening a fresh connection everytime. Unless your application is very complex, a single connection should be ok. So no need for a pool.

Comment: I was a bit puzzled by all the "drivermanager is deprecated" impressions I got when looking for information on the subject. I surmise I can keep on using it for my relatively small desktop applications then! Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome..Most people dont program with DriverManager api directly anymore, its usually hidden behind library code.

Comment: OK, I see, but isn't that the same thing as using a basic, non-pooled datasource in that case?